# How to share logic between cases in pattern matching

Tags: scala, akka

I have an actor where I need do something based on message hierarhy:

```
object MyActor {

    trait UpdateMessage
    case class UpdateOne() extends UpdateMessage
    case class UpdateTwo() extends UpdateMessage
    case class Other()

}
```

There is a same logic on `UpdateMessage`. You can see, that `updateOneAndTwoLogic()` calls two times:

```
class MyActor extends Actor {

    def receive: PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = {
        case UpdateOne() => {
          updateOneAndTwoLogic() //repeated
          updateOne()
        }
        case UpdateTwo() => {
          updateOneAndTwoLogic() //repeated
          updateTwo()
        }
        case Other() => {
          ...
        }
    }
}
```

In `UntypedActor` from java api, I can do something like:

```
public void onReceive(Object message) {
    if (message instanceof UpdateMessage)
        updateOneAndTwoLogic();
    if (message instanceof UpdateOne)
        updateOne();
    if (message instanceof UpdateTwo)
        UpdateTwo();
    if (message instanceof Other)
        ...
}
```

where `updateOneAndTwoLogic()` don't repeats.

How to remove duplicate calls in scala version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `|` syntax while pattern matching in Scala.

```
case msg @ (UpdateOne() | UpdateTwo()) => 
   updateOneAndTwoLogic()
   msg match {
     case UpdateOne() => updateOne()
     case UpdateTwo() => updateTwo()
   }
```

*Suggestion*

use case objects instead of case classes with empty parenthesis.